# Why IF condition does not work with "OR" in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, syntax

Problem is that, `OR` is not work with IF condition in python 3, If I write multiple `IF` condition then it's working fine as below :

```
s1 has 3 matches in text[i]
s2 has 1 matches in text[i]
text[i] is read line by line and contain s1 OR s1
```

Not work :

```
c=0
if s1 in text[i] or s2 in text[i]:
  c = c + 1
```

Output :

```
3    # here correct total 4 condition, s1 true as 3 and s2 true as 1 !
```

Work :

```
c=0
if s1 in text[i] :
   c = c + 1 
if s2 in text[i] :
   c = c + 1
```

**Desire/correct result is 4**

How can write both condition in single line ?

Comment: The first code leaves `c` at 0 or 1. The second code leaves `c` at 0, 1 or 2. Neither of them sets it to 4. Neither of them outputs anything.

Comment: @khelwood i updated question & Let me if any doubt

Comment: It appears you are looking for multiple matches. You can't use `in` for that because `in` stops looking at the first match. Look up the string method `count()` and use that instead.

Comment: Perhaps you would like to post a [mre] that actually exhibits the behaviour you are describing.

Comment: Consider what happens if both `s1` and `s2` are in `text[i]`.

Comment: @Kemp `s1` and `s2` never in one line,

Answer (score 1):

Because you are no iterating for every truth you can get from the if.

The following code will give you what you wish for.

```
s1 = "f"
s2 = "b"
text = "foo foo buzz"


def check_if_in_str(x, I):
    return x in text[i]


variables = [s1, s2]
c = 0
for i in text:
    for variable in variables:
        if check_if_in_str(variable, I):
            c += 1
```

keep in mind that is not a best practice to invent the wheel and you should work with the set function count()
see this reference for more info:
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/count